# Redirigir con htaccess una URL antigua a una nueva

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy intentando redirigir a través de htaccess una URL antigua a su nueva estructura. Por ejemplo, en vez de www.unawebcualquiera.org/contacto/ a www.unawebcualquiera.org/es/contacto/

Antes del cambio en .htaccess tenía esto:

```
RewriteRule ^contacto/ contacto.php [L]
```

Y ahora para redireccionar estoy intentado con:

```
RewriteRule ^contacto/ contacto.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^contacto/$ es/contacto/ [L,R=301]
```

Pero me devuelte el siguiente error:

> Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido
>   completar su solicitud. Se ha producido un error interno en el
>   servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud. O el servidor está
>   sobrecargado o ha habido un fallo en la ejecución de un programa CGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las 2 reglas están colisionando. Deberías ponerlo en el orden inverso:

```
RewriteRule ^contacto/?$ es/contacto/    [NC,R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^es/contacto/?$ contacto.php [NC,L]
```

- La primera redirecciona y la solicitud se va con la redirección.
- Una segunda solicitud (o cualquier solicitud a `es/contacto/`) no coincide con la primera regla, y reescribe a contacto.php (revisá si el PHP va ahí o en `es/contacto.php`).
- Nunca uses una redirección 301 para probar, es muy peligroso porque son fuertemebte cacheadas. Empezá con un 302 y si estás muy seguro de que funciona y de que no se va a modificar en el futuro, podría cambiarse por un 301.